# How can I start a vbs script from VB.Net and pass arguments to the vb script started

Tags: vb.net, string, process, arguments, wsh

I need to execute a command like "cscript OSPP.vbs /dstatus" from a visual basic App. I am using the bellow code but I have not been able to transfer the argument "dstatus" to the OSPP.vbs. How could I do that? Any help

```
    Dim start As New ProcessStartInfo
    Dim task As New Process
    Dim so As IO.StreamReader

    start.FileName = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cscript.exe"
    start.Arguments = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\OSPP.vbs /dstatus"""

    start.UseShellExecute = False
    start.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    start.RedirectStandardError = False        

    task.StartInfo = start
    task.Start()
    so = task.StandardOutput
    task.WaitForExit()
    MsgBox(so.ReadToEnd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments are not well formed, since the path has white spaces you need to enclose it between double quotes.

Try this:

```
Dim args as string =
     String.Format("""{0}"" ""{1}""", 
                   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\OSPP.vbs", 
                   "/dstatus") 

start.FileName = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cscript.exe"
start.Arguments = args
```